# Dialogflow missing parameters value in my weebhook

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I've just started using DialogFlow, so I created an Entity and an Intent, I expected to find the value of the entity in the request that dialog flow sends to my intent. So what i am missing? Maybe some configuration?

Dialogflow:

[image]

conversation:

[image]

dialog flow request to my webhook:

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHH-9zhFI8dblLY0LrQtm5Q-KzktqRxIwLeBbj81azEqPljSUHGUUJ6QmHX1kWuuElNIUTADqeAxFA",
    "locale": "it-IT",
    "lastSeen": "2018-11-09T16:23:17Z"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "ABwppHGh2EhXREkW2aiYNmbMz7aTVtLrOSW0spPJ4joKTPlaJ6OKRZTto4xwpjv5gtUzRT4cb3VGHfhqiw",
    "type": "ACTIVE",
    "conversationToken": "[]"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "orari aula 1d150"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "orari aula 1d150",
          "textValue": "orari aula 1d150"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "availableSurfaces": [
    {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
        },
        {
          "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "requestType": "SIMULATOR"
}
```

UPDATE:
Dialogflow match my intent correctly and send back to my webhook a JSON in which the information on the values of my parameters is missing, this is the problem. Maybe I set wrong value to entity?

Comment: That looks like either the "google" portion of the JSON sent to your webhook, or the information from the "request" tab in the simulator. Either way, it will not contain parameter information that is processed by Dialogflow. Can you update your question to either include the Dialogflow portion, or what intent it seems to be matching? Is that the fallback intent? Can you show the code for your webhook?

Comment: I know it seems that dialogflow does not pass the value of the entities to my webhook and I can not understand why. maybe I have to set the context? I'm sure it has nothing to do with my webhook I copied the json from the google simulator console. @Prisoner

Comment: The simulator doesn't show the parameters, which is why seeing the code you're using will help us either understand how you're handling the parameters or suggest other debugging avenues to investigate.